# Trying to combine spreadsheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have a dozen or so columns of data in excel with the headers Company, and Funded Balance. The funded balances change year to year and I want to make a timeline how the funded balance changes for each year for each company.

The issue is that every year some companies don't have a funded balance and some new companies are added in. Is there a way to combine two or more spreadsheets so that the companies will all be listed alphabetically with the data listed by the year? I've attached pictures below to illustrate what I mean:

Column 1:
[image: Column 1:]

Column 2: [image]

Finished Product:  [image]

I'm fairly inexperienced in VBA, so a step by step solution would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can't expect full code here. Show what you have tried .we will assist from there.

Comment: I don't have any code written yet. I was hoping that there would be an easy solution given that it seems like a fairly straightforward problem.

Comment: As I read once on some SO user motto: "First solve the problem, then write the code". I think you should start making a list of all companies. For this, I suggest a loop for going through all your worksheets. Inside that loop, a second loop to scan all rows in the worksheet, and copy company name to a result worksheet (checking if name already exists).

Comment: _"So, I have a dozen or so columns of data ..."_ does _"columns"_ mean _"worksheets"_?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's important to know that nobody here will write your code for you. I'm afraid that's not what this website is for, and is against the guidelines anyway. There are plenty of great online resources for teaching yourself the basics of VBA - http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html for example.

Based on your description of the problem, I don't quite understand why you need to write VBA code in order to solve it.

I would:

1) copy and paste all data into a single spreadsheet

2) sort alphabetically by company name

3) use excel's inbuilt "Subtotal" function

4) a dialogue box will appear. The options you want to select are: at each change in company name, use function sum, add subtotal to [funded balance 2005],[funded balance 2006], etc.

This should sum up the funded balance for each year, for each company, in a single spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for a non-VBA solution:

```
1. Place all of your tables on top of each other
2. Remove the first two rows and any intervening blank rows 
   from all tables except the first one. It should look like one long table.
3. In the first blank row of the second column put: 
   =IF(SUMIF($A$3:$A$8,$A3,B$3:B$8)=0,"",SUMIF($A$3:$A$8,$A3,B$3:B$8)) and adjust it 
   for your correct last row.
4. Drag the formula down (for the neccesary number of rows) and over one column.
5. With all the formulas selected, right click and hold any edge of the selection, 
   move off and back on again and paste as values only. (You must do this step for it to work properly)
6. Copy and paste the company names.
7. Select the three columns of your new rows and remove duplicates.
   Uncheck My Data has headers. 
8. Sort the columns.
```